# Are there different kinds of system variables in jboss?

Tags: jboss, jboss-cli

In jboss-cli I can do

```
[standalone@localhost:10990 /] /system-property=foo.bar:add(value=baz)
{"outcome" => "success"}

[standalone@localhost:10990 /] /system-property=foo.bar:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"value" => "baz"}
}
```

I can list all the system variables with

```
[standalone@localhost:10990 /] /core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-attribute(name=system-properties)
```

One of them is jboss.home.dir. I do:

```
[standalone@localhost:10990 /] /system-property=jboss.home.dir:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"system-property\" => \"jboss.home.dir\")]' not foun
d",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

So this is another kind of system variable?

I read that I can do:

```
[standalone@localhost:10990 /] :resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "D:\\dev\\eap_wildfly\\eap-7.4.0"
}
```

But that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `system-property` resource is a way to set system properties or override them. In some cases, depending on when the system property is accessed, that resource might not work.

The `jboss.home.dir` property is a system property that is always set from the server. You cannot override this in the `system-property` resource either. If you do:

```
/system-property=jboss.home.dir:add(value=${jboss.home.dir})
```

The command would fail with:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYSRV0115: System property jboss.home.dir cannot be set via the xml configuration file or from a management client; it's value must be known at initial process start so it can only set from the command line",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

You could however set the `jboss.home.dir` system property in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable or via the command line like:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.home.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/
```

It's not that there are multiple types of system properties, there are just multiple ways to set them. Some properties, like `jboss.home.dir` or system properties required by the JVM, cannot be set in the `system-property` configuration resource. However, the `system-property` configuration simply sets the system property, e.g. `System.setProperty(name, value)`.